# How can I change Azure data factory pipeline parameter dynamically?I want to assign new value to pipeline parameter from 'Metadata activity'

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I want to obtain a parameter from pipeline output. Currently as per my knowledge Azure data factory pipeline output can not be customized. Hence I want to pass my output string in pipeline parameter, to be able to extract it from pipeline output json.

Answer (score 0):

The output of a pipeline is an output of an activity with in that pipeline . You can use the "Execute Pipeline" activity and trigger a new  pipeline .

Comment: That'll create a new pipeline run. Can you suggest some other workround? I want to set the parameter dynamically, without creating a new pipeline run.

Comment: Pipeline run logs doesn't have output field, also there's no way I can customize the logs.